# Cordova Email Composer Plugin using Angular HTML not rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I just started messing with the Cordova Email Composer Plugin for my Ionic app and I noticed the plugin doesn't look like it supports Angular HTML code?. I was wondering if there may be an alternative for this issue or, perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Page.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

import { ReapService } from '../../services/reap-service';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-offline-data',
  templateUrl: 'offline-data.html',
})
export class OfflineDataPage {
  private offlineData:any [] =[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public storage: Storage,
              public viewCtrl: ViewController,
              private emailComposer: EmailComposer,
              public reap: ReapService) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.storage.get('offlineSubmission').then((data)=>{
        this.offlineData=data;
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
  sendEmail(){
    this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
     if(available) {
       //Now we know we can send
     }
    },(err) => {
      this.reap.presentToast('Error Emailing Data');
    });

    let email = {
      to: 'email@email.com',
      cc: 'email@email.com',
      //bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
      attachments: [
        //'file://img/logo.png',
        //'res://icon.png',
        //'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
        //'file://README.pdf'
      ],
      subject: 'Test',
      body: `
      <div *ngFor="let data of offlineData;let i = index">

        <div *ngIf="data?.Type=='GPS'">
          <h1>{{i+1}}</h1>
          <h2 class="bold">Form - {{data?.Type}}</h2>
          <p>Well ID - {{data?.Info[0].ID}}</p>
          <p>Lat - {{data?.Info[1]['Lat']}}</p>
          <p>Lon - {{data?.Info[2].Lon}}</p>
        </div>


        <ion-card-content *ngIf="data?.Type=='Project'">
          <h1>{{i+1}}</h1>
          <h2 class="bold">Form - {{data?.Type}}</h2>
          <p>Project Name - {{data?.Info[0].project.projectName}}</p>
          <p>Location - {{data?.Info[0].project.Location.Location}}</p>
          <p>Company Man - {{data?.Info[0].project.companyMan}}</p>
          <p>AFE - {{data?.Info[0].project.orderNumber}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>

        <ion-card-content *ngIf="data?.Type=='WO'">
          <h1>{{i+1}}</h1>
          <h2 class="bold">Form - Work Order</h2>
          <p>Project - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].project.Name}}</p>
          <p>Location - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].Location.Location}}</p>
          <p>Company Man - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].companyMan}}</p>
          <p>Current Date - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].currentDate}}</p>
          <p>AFE - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].workOrder}}</p>
          <p>Foreman - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].foreman}}</p>
          <p>Start Time - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].startTime}}</p>
          <p>End Time - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].endTime}}</p>
          <p>Representative - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].representative}}</p>
          <p>Job Description - {{data?.Info[0].wo[0].description}}</p>

          <br>
          <h2 class="bold">Sub Form - Equipment</h2>
          <br>
          <div *ngFor="let subData of data.Info[4].Equipment">
          <p>Name - {{subData?.Name}}</p>
          <p>Starting Odometer - {{subData?.Odometer}}</p>
          <p>Ending Odometer - {{subData?.endingOdometer}}</p>
          <br>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2 class="bold">Sub Form - Labor</h2>
          <br>
          <div *ngFor="let subData of data.Info[5].Labor">
          <p>Empoloyee - {{subData?.FullName}}</p>
          <p>Hours - {{subData?.Hours}}</p>
          <br>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2 class="bold">Sub Form - Extra Labor</h2>
          <br>
          <div *ngFor="let subData of data.Info[9].extraLabor">
          <p>Name - {{subData?.Name}}</p>
          <p>Hours - {{subData?.Hours}}</p>
          <br>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2 class="bold">Sub Form - Misc.</h2>
          <br>
          <div *ngFor="let subData of data.Info[6].Misc">
          <p>Description - {{subData?.description}}</p>
          <p>Quantity - {{subData?.quantity}}</p>
          <br>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2 class="bold">Sub Form - Job Description</h2>
          <br>
          <div *ngFor="let subData of data.Info[7].JobDescription">
          <p>Job Description - {{subData?.jobDescription.ItemDescription}}</p>
          <p>Quantity - {{subData?.quantity}}</p>
          <p>Hours/Days/Cost - {{subData?.each}}</p>
          <br>
          </div>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
      `,
      isHtml: true
    };

    // Send a text message using default options
    this.emailComposer.open(email);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on the plugin, the only thing is the html code looks like this,

[image: Email ScreenShop]

Any recommendations with getting this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you're going to put 'around text, make sure to close it as well before you inject variables'. Your Html is working, but because you don't close the ' right before the variables, it's being processed as a string.

Take the following part of your code as example:

```
body: `
  <div *ngFor="let data of offlineData;let i = index">

    <div *ngIf="data?.Type=='GPS'">
      <h1>{{i+1}}</h1>
      <h2 class="bold">Form - {{data?.Type}}</h2>
      <p>Well ID - {{data?.Info[0].ID}}</p>
      <p>Lat - {{data?.Info[1]['Lat']}}</p>
      <p>Lon - {{data?.Info[2].Lon}}</p>
    </div>
```

right after the body tag, there is a '
that means that everything from there on is being treated as a string, so javascript is not going to process any javascript in that page, since it generated it itself.
better practise would be to inject the variables in the text while generating it, or using a template file with that html code in it.

```
body: `
  <div *ngFor="let data of offlineData;let i = index">

    <div *ngIf="data?.Type=='GPS'">
      <h1>'+ {{i+1}} +'</h1>
      <h2 class="bold">Form - '+ {{data?.Type}} +'</h2>
      <p>Well ID - '+ {{data?.Info[0].ID}} +'</p>
      <p>Lat - '+ {{data?.Info[1]['Lat']}} +'</p>
      <p>Lon - '+ {{data?.Info[2].Lon}} +'</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Perhaps show me an example?

Comment: sorry for the brief reaction, i'm actually at work right now. i hope this edit helps.

Comment: Hmmm I tried and it is still printing the ' as a string as well. Is it possible to just send the array in JSON format? I don't necessarily have to print all of the values like I have. I just need to be able to extract the data from the email.

Comment: Well yes, that's how it's normally done in angular. You would just provide a template, and create an object in your scope. Then you can read out the variables in the template. Are you running an MVC ASP.Net application? I would just post the data to the API, and then let that generate and send the email.

Comment: I'm Using Ionic 3 Framework. This particular feature I'm implementing is if for some reason the API call fails, the user can store the form submission and I'm determining ways to be able to export the data. The app is going to be used where there isn't always a good amount of service.